# How do I add a custom select field in my pod?

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I am using Podsframework. I have created a pod called 'media'. Inside my pod I want to add a select field with multiple options(like 'online','offline','press'). So whenever someone is creating a new media he/she will have to select one of these options.I tried using helpers but didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use the relationship field, with the custom simple option?

We saw that use case often so we built it into Pods 2.0